# How to show all coupon codes in cms page

Tags: magento-1, cms, coupon

I need to show all coupons codes in cms page. For this i have created a custom phtml in templete and in this template i have wrote the following code :

```
<?php
$rulesCollection = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection();
foreach ($rulesCollection as $rule) {
    $coupon = $rule->getCoupons();
}

$rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load();
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    $conditions = $rule->getConditionsSerialized();
    var_dump($conditions);
}
?>
```

and add a block in cms page :

```
{{block type="core/template" name="email_coupon" template="email/coupon.phtml"}}
```

But nothing is showing please help me .

Comment: what is the issue in code ,please explain

Answer (score 3):

instead of load whole collection i suggest you use sql query with help of my custom function

```
  public function getAllActiveCoupon(){

        $coupontable = 'salesrule_coupon';
        $today = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
        $select = $this->_read->select()
                ->from('salesrule', array('name', 'description'))
                 ->joinLeft(
                        array('sc' => $coupontable),
                        "(sc.rule_id = salesrule.rule_id) AND (sc.expiration_date IS NULL OR sc.expiration_date >= '{$today}')",
                        array('code'))

                ->where('is_active = ?', 1)
                ->where('from_date IS NULL OR from_date <= ?', $today)
                ->where('to_date IS NULL OR to_date >= ?', $today)
                ->where('is_rss = ?', 1);

        $result = $this->_read->fetchAll($select); //fetch all active couopon
        return $result;       
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
in view file

$coupons = $this->getActiveCoupon();
 <?php
        if (!empty($coupons)) :
            foreach ($coupons as $coupon):
                ?>
                <li>
                    <h2><?php echo $coupon['name']; ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $coupon['description']; ?> </p>
                </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

you can change condition depends on requirement